# Does it make more logical sense to model the discrete FFT output as a categorical variable or a numerical variable?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, signal-processing, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am training a time-series data classifier and some of my features are the output of CT FFT.  The results are of course discrete frequencies.  I understand that they are in numerical order and higher frequencies correspond to components of the original signal with shorter cycles, and therefore I can arguably consider them an ordered set of numbers and treat them as any other numerical feature.

But I am very far removed from DSP and even statistics, so to me it seems that it isn't really meaningful to treat the frequencies as an ordered set.  I.E. I would think 4 of 32 (I am using 64 samples) isn't HIGHER or MORE than 2 of 32 and 3 of 32 isn't BETWEEN 2 and 4.  This makes me think that categorical methods are more applicable to this sort of data.

I hope this made some sense, thanks for your help in clearing this up.

Comment: The FFT will output a vector of complex values representing the amplitude and phase at each frequency. Frequency itself is a continuous variable. But, what you have is a vector with a particular structure relating the entries--they're indexed by frequency. Classifiers often don't consider this kind of structure at all--the input vector is simply treated as a list of values whose order doesn't really matter. But, there are exceptions, like convolutional neural nets. So, the way frequency is treated here depends on the details of the classifier. Perhaps you can edit to say more about this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I edited my post.  I am not passing raw 1-dimensional data into a network.  There are ~100 features and a convolutional component as well as an attention component.  I am hoping the classifier would be able to separate the data into meta clusters or hidden states (like HMM or KMeans) to help select among shallower strategies